# devtools::document looking for uncalled package

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I am getting an error when I run `devtools::document()` on my simple test `R` file. To me it looks like `devtools` is asking to include the `imports` package in the `DESCRIPTION` file, but my test file is using `import` not `imports`. Am I missing something for the package name?

My `R` script, `DESCRIPTION` file, console output with the error, and folder and file contents below.

**test.R file**

```
#' This is the title.
#'
#' This is the description.
#' 

import::from(dplyr, filter)

test_str <- "Hello world"
```

**DESCRIPTION file**

```
Package: test
Title: test
Version: 0.1
Depends: R (>= 3.1.0)
Imports:
    dplyr,
    import
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
Encoding: UTF-8
RoxygenNote: 7.1.1
```

**Console output**

```
devtools::document()
Updating test documentation
Loading test
Error in as.environment(where) : 
  no item called "imports" on the search list
```

**File and folder structure**

```
~\test\
      \DESCRIPTION  
      \NAMESPACE
      \R\
      \R\test.R
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `import::from` rather than using the roxygen `#' @importFrom dplyr filter` type syntax when building a package?

Comment: I'm probably confusing concepts. From reading the roxygen2 vignette, I'm avoiding `@importFrom` due to poor readability. The suggestion from the vignette is to use `pkg::fun()` but this seems ugly when using the same function many times. I was hoping to use `import::from` so I can directly call (in this example) `filter()` instead of `dplyr::filter()`, whilst also avoiding importing complete packages.

Comment: Im not familiar with `import::from` but from a quick glance at the documentation it doesn't appear to be appropriate for package code. It may make sense for user scripts. If you want your package to pass CRAN checks, then you'll need to use `pkg::fun()` style syntax.

Comment: I believe `imports` is not related to the `imports` package, but: "The imported objects are placed in a separate entity in the search path which by default is named `imports`." https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/import/vignettes/import.html